# RoR, postgresql gemspec missing or broken when running console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, openssl, libssl, gemspecs

My MacBook Air suddenly stoped working so I had to manually reboot...
After that, when I run a rake test to fill a pg database it crashed. Now I'm at the point where I can't even run the console. These are the errors, any suggestions will be much appreciated! Thanks.

`rails c`

```
Loading development environment (Rails 5.2.4.2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    45: from -e:1:in `<main>'
    44: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    43: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    42: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `load'
    41: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    40: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `block in load'
    39: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `load'
    38: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `load'
    37: from /Users/gabrielgz/code/gabrielgz92/data_live_feed/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    36: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
    35: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
    34: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
    33: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    32: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    31: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    30: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    29: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    28: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    27: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.2/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    26: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
    25: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    24: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    23: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    22: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.2/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:96:in `perform'
    21: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.2/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:19:in `start'
    20: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.2/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:64:in `start'
    19: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb.rb:376:in `start'
    18: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/init.rb:17:in `setup'
    17: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/init.rb:112:in `init_config'
    16: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/init.rb:112:in `new'
    15: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/locale.rb:32:in `initialize'
    14: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/locale.rb:108:in `load'
    13: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/locale.rb:124:in `find'
    12: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/locale.rb:145:in `search_file'
    11: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/locale.rb:157:in `each_localized_path'
    10: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/locale.rb:167:in `each_sublocale'
     9: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/locale.rb:158:in `block in each_localized_path'
     8: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/irb/locale.rb:150:in `block in search_file'
     7: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:213:in `try_activate'
     6: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1063:in `find_by_path'
     5: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1063:in `find'
     4: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:148:in `each'
     3: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:148:in `each'
     2: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1065:in `block in find_by_path'
     1: from /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/remote_specification.rb:106:in `method_missing'
/Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/stub_specification.rb:97:in `_remote_specification': The gemspec for pg-1.2.3 at /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/specifications/pg-1.2.3.gemspec was missing or broken. Try running `gem pristine pg -v 1.2.3` to fix the cached spec. (Bundler::GemspecError)
```

***Last line: The gemspec for pg-1.2.3 at /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/specifications/pg-1.2.3.gemspec was missing or broken. Try running `gem pristine pg -v 1.2.3` to fix the cached spec. (Bundler::GemspecError)***

Then:
`gem pristine pg -v 1.2.3`

````
  Referenced from: /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle
  Expected in: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _SSL_library_init
  Referenced from: /Users/gabrielgz/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle
  Expected in: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib

[1]    29614 abort      gem pristine pg -v 1.2.3```
````

Comment: Have you tried repairing rbenv? Also have you installed any of this using Brew? I would try updating/repairing Gem, Brew, rbenv, etc.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Using rbenv, I reinstalled Ruby but now the error is ```cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)```

Comment: Have you tried `gem install bundler` ?

Comment: I finally did a hard reset of my mac and installed everything from scratch. Thanks for help anyway

Answer (score 1):

For people on Linux, I solved this issue running this command :

```
gem update --system
```

because I had updated my system

I found this command here : https://github.com/sickill/rainbow/issues/44